# Combine several mb_ereg_replace()-calls

Tags: php, regex, multibyte-functions

How can I combine these replacements into one regular expression?

```
$style = $node->getAttribute("style");
$style = mb_ereg_replace("(direction:[[:space:]]*(rtl|ltr);)", "", $style) . " direction: {$direction};";  // remove existing direction-attribute and add the new one
$style = mb_ereg_replace("(^[[:space:]]*)|([[:space:]]*$)", "", $style); // trim spaces at the end and beginning
$style = mb_ereg_replace("([[:space:]]){2,}", " ", $style); // limit spaces to one at a time
$node->setAttribute("style", $style);
```

The expressions work as expected but I would like to combine them to less then three replace-statements.
I can not just replace the existing direction-attribute, as I don't know if there is any.

**edit**
added alternation to the first two replacements:

```
$style = mb_ereg_replace("(direction:[[:space:]]*(rtl|ltr);)|(^[[:space:]]*)|([[:space:]]*$)", "", $style) . " direction: {$direction};";  // remove existing direction-attribute and trim spaces at the end and beginning and add the new one
$style = mb_ereg_replace("([[:space:]]){2,}", " ", $style); // limit spaces to one at a time
```

Comment: You can just list them as [alternatives](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: I know, but I am asking about [mb_ereg_replace()](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php). If you can point me to a better solution than just telling me that something I did not ask about should not be used I would be glad, @Truth.

Comment: @Truth: [`mb_ereg`](http://php.net/mb_ereg) is not. (Also deprecated doesn't mean it could realistically be removed anytime soon.)

Comment: @mario, I see how I could combine the first two as alternatives. But what about the third one, which does not replace the matches with nothing but with one space.

Comment: @fragmentedreality: How about `preg_replace()`?

Comment: You can't combine it if the last regex accomplishes a different task. Except of course if you can capture the last alternatives´ first space `(\s)`  and use a `$5` placeholder trick to reinject it just for that case.

Comment: @Truth, I did not know, that `preg_replace()` [supports UTF-8](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). @mario, thank you for the hints. I guess this is a bit to heavy just to have clean HTML-output. I think I will just leave the blanks in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I'd do it: trim() replaces your 2nd regex (unless you want to keep the linebreaks, if there will be some)

I did it with preg_replace, what you should use instead of ereg_functions (its slightly different, but nothing complex)

```
$style = trim(preg_replace('~direction:(\\s*?)(rtl|ltr);~','',$style) . " direction: {$direction};");
$style = preg_replace('~(\\s*?){2,}~',' ',$style);
```

Comment: Sorry, that gives me: `style=" d i r e c t i o n :   r t l ; "` – and that comes from the second `preg_replace()`.

Comment: `$direction` is either "rtl" or "ltr" and `$style` is an abritrary css-directive. In the best case it is empty in the worst case it contains stuff including an `direction: rtl;` You can start with `$style = "direction: ltr:"; $direction = "rtl";`. That is all that is coming into the function.